# Why am getting null object error in this activity?

Tags: android, android-widget, retrofit, retrofit2, android-lifecycle

Am using retrofit to fetch data..I tried to launch the app from from widget. But the app is crashing because of the null object. I tried checking the object...it is not null after fetching data from API but later it is becoming null .. why ? is there any way to properly fetch data.. how apps fetch data after widget clicking ?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.master_list);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Checking to see if the app is opened by widget by checking existence of startFromWidget value from intent
    if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("stringFromWidget") != null) {

        //App opened by widget
        fromWidget = true;

        //Getting last stored value from Database assign it to temp
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(DBContract.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null);
        assert c != null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        String temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBContract.RECIPE_NAME));

        //Fetching data from API
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<ApiResponce>> call = apiService.getResponce();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ApiResponce>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ApiResponce>> call, Response<List<ApiResponce>> response) {
                reciepeObject = response.body().get(3);

                //Making sure data is received 
                Toast.makeText(MasterListClass.this, reciepeObject.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//No null object error ...working fine 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ApiResponce>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("networkError", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    //if the app not opened by widget get the object from the intent 
    else {
        reciepeObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.object));
    }

    //Null Object error from recipeObject.getName().. why ?
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(reciepeObject.getName());
```

Logcat:

05-11 12:42:48.558 6978-6978/facebooklogintest.cavepass.com.bakingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: facebooklogintest.cavepass.com.bakingapp, PID: 6978
                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{facebooklogintest.cavepass.com.bakingapp/facebooklogintest.cavepass.com.bakingapp.UI.MasterListClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String facebooklogintest.cavepass.com.bakingapp.ModelClasses.ApiResponce.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String facebooklogintest.cavepass.com.bakingapp.ModelClasses.ApiResponce.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at facebooklogintest.cavepass.com.bakingapp.UI.MasterListClass.onCreate(MasterListClass.java:100)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
05-11 12:42:48.621 2661-6708/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ContentStoreEUAS: Failed to commit the deferred actions
05-11 12:42:49.066 2057-2086/system_process E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: Unknown animationType=0

Comment: Add you logcat please. I think the problem is in getting value from bundle data. Before getting data from bundle, first check whether the key is available or not by `getIntent().getExtras().hasString("key")` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(reciepeObject.getName());
```

inside `onResponse`

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ApiResponce>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ApiResponce>> call, Response<List<ApiResponce>> response) {
                reciepeObject = response.body().get(3);

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(reciepeObject.getName());                   
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                Toast.makeText(MasterListClass.this, reciepeObject.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//No null object error ...working fine 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ApiResponce>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("networkError", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

because REST calls are asynchronous so will take some time to complete and the response can only be used once `onResponse` is triggered

Comment: How should i proceed with data if it takes some time...like adding data to recyclerView etc.. ?

Comment: create a method , add you code in it, the call that method from within `onResponse`, pass the parameter if required

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding